# How to make an array of objects in python

Tags: python

In Java, we make an array of objects with a fixed size as follows

ArrayClass array_of_objects[]=new ArrayClass[10];

but how can I make a list of objects in python with a fixed size?

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty list of size 5

```
lst = [None] * 5
```

Comment: this makes a list, but OP wanted an array. They are not the same, but very similar

Comment: @EmiOB I don't think that, coming from Java, the OP knows the difference, and most likely, they mean list. (Especially, considering the last sentence.)

Comment: I also think :D

Comment: This doesn't have a fixed size, though

Comment: @bereal fair point. Just thought it was important to note that they are two different things in python :)

Answer (score 2):

use `numpy` like below:

```
import numpy as np
size = 2
np.array([None]*size, dtype=object)
```

Output:

```
array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

you can use this like below:

```
arr = np.array([None]*2, dtype=object)
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 'str'
```

Output:

```
array([1, 'str'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Numpy seems like overkill for the question asked

Comment: @OneCricketeer hahahah:)))